# Laravel how to define 3 relationships with one model?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Model which is called Championship. Championship may have 3 judges which are called Main Judge, Main Secretary and Judge Operator.

All of them linked to User Model and stored in the database as user ID.

My relationships looks like this

```
class Championship extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'championships';

    public function mainJudge()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'main_judge');
    }

    public function mainSecretary()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'main_secretary');
    }

    public function judgeOperator()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id','judge_operator');
    }
}
```

But I can't undertand how to define inverse relationship in User model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function sex()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Sex');
    }

    public function player()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Player', 'user_id');
    }

    public function championship()
    {
    ????
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add it like you are adding other relations :

```
public function championship()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Championship');
}
```

When you do :

```
$championship = Championship::find($id);
$mainJudge = $championship->mainJudge;
$mainSecretary = $championship->mainSecretary;

// All objects will be exactly same
dd($mainJudge->championship,$mainSecretary->championship,$championship);
```

I assume all the user records have a foreign key to `championships` table `championship_id`

When you call the `$user->championship` relation it will return you the `championship` wrt to its foreign key `championship_id`

No need to worry you are just confusing the inverse relations:

See it this way:

Your `mainJudge`, `mainSecretary`, `judgeOperators` are of type `App\User` and every user have a `championship_id` when you will call the `(App\User)->championship` it will always return you its respective championship or `null` if the `championship_id` is empty.
Its just matter of perspective.

Just try the above code it will clear out your confusion.